# Sending String through Intent between two SherlockFragments

Tags: java, android, android-intent, webview, actionbarsherlock

Im getting the following Stacktrack and cant seem how to resolve. Im sending a string to another `SherlockFragment` with the following code .

### Sending Intent

```
   @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(final WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.contains("google.com")
                || url.contains("google.com/images")) {
            Log.i("WebView",
                    "URL is part of the MainActiviy" + "URL = " + url);
            view.loadUrl(url);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            Log.i("WebView",
                    "URL is not part of MainActivity" + "URL = " + url);
            Intent settings = new Intent();
            settings.setClassName("org.example.code",
                    "org.example.code.FullBrowser");
            settings.putExtra("url", url);
            startActivity(settings);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

### Receiving Intent

```
WebView web;
String url;
static ProgressBar progressBar;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inf, ViewGroup grp, Bundle icicle) {
    View v = inf.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, grp, false);
    web = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    return v;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle extras = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
        url = extras.getString("url");
        web.loadUrl(url);
}
```

### Recommended Change

```
url = extras.getString("url");

        Bundle arguments = new Bundle(); arguments.putString("url", url); 
        FullBrowser fragment = new FullBrowser(); fragment.setArguments(arguments); 
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.webView, fragment).commit();
        web.loadUrl(url);
```

Still giving me the following~

### LogCat

```
06-09 23:15:24.403: E/AndroidRuntime(8574): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-09 23:15:24.403: E/AndroidRuntime(8574): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{org.example.code/org.example.code.FullBrowser}: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.example.code.FullBrowser cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
06-09 23:15:24.403: E/AndroidRuntime(8574):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2172)
06-09 23:15:24.403: E/AndroidRuntime(8574):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2296)
06-09 23:15:24.403: E/AndroidRuntime(8574):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:151)
06-09 23:15:24.403: E/AndroidRuntime(8574):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
06-09 23:15:24.403: E/AndroidRuntime(8574):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-09 23:15:24.403: E/AndroidRuntime(8574):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-09 23:15:24.403: E/AndroidRuntime(8574):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
06-09 23:15:24.403: E/AndroidRuntime(8574):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-09 23:15:24.403: E/AndroidRuntime(8574):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-09 23:15:24.403: E/AndroidRuntime(8574):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
06-09 23:15:24.403: E/AndroidRuntime(8574):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
06-09 23:15:24.403: E/AndroidRuntime(8574):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-09 23:15:24.403: E/AndroidRuntime(8574): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.example.code.FullBrowser cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
06-09 23:15:24.403: E/AndroidRuntime(8574):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1071)
06-09 23:15:24.403: E/AndroidRuntime(8574):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2163)
```

Comment: Is org.example.code.FullBrowser an activity or a fragment? You said you are passing arguments to another fragment but you are starting an activity.

Comment: `Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
    arguments.putString(“myparameter”, id);
    MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(arguments);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.item_detail_container, fragment).commit();` this is the way you pass and start a fragment.

Comment: Its Fragment to Fragment

Comment: Check my second comment above. What you are doing is trying to start an activity instead of adding a fragment to your activity.

Comment: Added your recommended code with eclipse recommended changes

Comment: r you still starting the activity? Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.example.code.FullBrowser cannot be cast to android.app.Activity